# use same function for different types

Tags: python, types

I have following function:

```
def calculate_digits(number: Union[int, float, str]) -> int:
    absolute_value: float = abs(number)
    rounded_value: int = math.floor(absolute_value)
    total_digits_needed: int = calculate_length_integer(rounded_value)
    return total_digits_needed
```

As you can see, I want to use this for different python types : int, float, str...
As the abs() only works for floats I was wondering, how do I deal best with this?
Do I need to write a function with if, elsif statement to do this, or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What would the behavour even be if a str was passed to this?

Comment: you can convert the number to float at the beginning itself `number = float(number)`.  And add a try and exception if there is catch errors.

Answer (score 1):

For me abs() works on int too...
I'm using python 3.9.

For example the code below works for me at least:

```
number = abs(3)
```

Check if you need to update

Comment: `abs()` has always worked on `int`, `float`, `complex`, and other numeric types (e.g., `decimal.Decimal`).

Answer (score 1):

First, `abs` doesn't just work for `float`s; it works for *numbers*. At the very least:

- `int`
- `float`
- `complex`
- `decimal.Decimal`

There may be others. You might even be able to use `numbers.Number` as the type hint, though I'm not sure if that might not be too broad.

Second, this function really should be two functions, as a string is quite different from a numeric type.

```
def calculate_digits(number: Union[int, float]) -> int:
    absolute_value = abs(number)
    rounded_value = math.floor(absolute_value)
    return cacalculate_length_integer(rounded_value)

def calculate_digits_from_string(n: str) -> int:
    x = ... # Convert the string to an appropriate number.
    # There isn't enough detail in the question to know
    # which strings can be appropriate converted; float(n)
    # might be sufficient, though it could fail for an arbitrary
    # string.
    return calculate_digts(x)
```

You could combine them again, but I wouldn't recommend it, as the work to
convert a string to a number should be kept separate.

```
def calculate_digits(number: Union[int, float, str]) -> int:
    if isinstance(number, str):
        number = ...  # Convert as above
    absolute_value = abs(number)
    rounded_value = math.floor(absolute_value)
    return cacalculate_length_integer(rounded_value)
```

Comment: This is for a school task, so I need to do it like this

Comment: Then it's a bad assignment. But the point is, the only problem you are facing is how to determine if the argument is a string that has to be converted to a numeric type, and you haven't mentioned what strings are possible inputs. Maybe `float(numbers)` is sufficient for any possible argument; maybe not.

Comment: What I was wondering. Is there a fancy way to determine 'oh this variable is a int, you need to use 'make_int_absolute', or 'oh this varibale is a int, use 'convert_to_absolute_int'. You know what I mean? Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can, but there's no need. `abs` already works for most numeric types. `abs(-3) == 3`; `abs(-3.5) == 3.5`, `abs(1 + 3j) == 3.1622776601683795`, `abs(Decimal("-3.6")) == Decimal('3.6')`, etc.